# Bootstrap Grid Custom Spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with having different sized buttons (a tags) with the bootstrap grid system. Right now, I have 4 different sized buttons, and they each take up 3 columns each. For example, I have 4 similar to this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">  <a href="#page-join-us" class="btn-slider">Button Text Here</a>

    </div>
```

My current setup (JSFiddle) is:

http://jsfiddle.net/cov4ca1z/17/

For right now, I'm not worried about how the buttons are overlapping when the window is shrunken down to mobile size. Ideally, what I'm looking for is something like this:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/wbp1sp.jpg

I played around with a couple different things, but I couldn't find anything that worked.

Thanks.

Comment: So... you want the links to fill the parent divs? I don't really understand.

Comment: I'd rather not have the buttons expanded to fill the columns, I just want them all next to each other with a small margin between them. The image (2nd link) should show it pretty well.

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding and adding col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 and col-lg-3 to each column class attribute? Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/cov4ca1z/19/

Comment: Removing the padding only takes away most of the gray background from the links. I also found no change in adding the col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 and col-lg-3, although it's probably a good idea to have them. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column widths in the Bootstrap grid system are fixed. If you put each button in its own column, it's going to be constrained by the size of that column, and it will behave independent of your other buttons. So, your very very long button is going to wrap within its own column.

It sounds like you want all the buttons to appear next to each other and have them wrap one at a time as the screen size expands/contracts. I updated your Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cov4ca1z/24/

I put all the buttons together in their own column and included a `float: left` in your `btn-slider` class:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#page-join-us" class="btn-slider">Medium</a>
        <a href="#your-progress" class="btn-slider">Very Very Very Very Long</a>
        <a href="#your-progress" class="btn-slider">Short</a>
        <a href="#your-progress" class="btn-slider">About Average Size</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! This is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, it's not working quite the same way on my actual website, as I am modifying a template that I haven't fully explored yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place do something like this?

```
<ul id="buttonList" class="list-inline">
<li><a href="#page-join-us" class="btn-slider">Medium Size</a></li>
<li><a href="#your-progress" class="btn-slider">Very Very Very Very Long</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then use CSS  to style `ul#buttonList li{}` to adjust the margins as you would like.

Comment: Great suggestion! It looks really good, except I don't get the button wrapping like I would with a grid. Is there someway to do this with the un-ordered lists?

Comment: What do you mean? Like the overlapping of each button like your current fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cov4ca1z/17/ ?

Comment: I just saw your mockup and you can just style those with CSS by giving them each their own class and styling them as needed. But according to your mockup just using padding on each "ul#buttonList li a" should do the trick. I can create a fiddle if you need it.